# Entity Framework Core - building a migration and getting unclear error saying I am adding a property twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have run a migration for my solution and am getting the following error.

> The property or navigation 'ClientNotes' cannot be added to the entity
>   type 'Client' because a property or navigation with the same name
>   already exists on entity type 'Client'.

This is my client entity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JobsLedger.INTERFACES;

namespace JobsLedger.DATA.ENTITIES
{
#nullable enable
    public class Client : IEntityBase, IAuditedEntityBase
    {
        public Client()
        {
            ClientNotes = new List<Note>();
            Jobs = new List<Job>();
        }

        public string ClientNo { get; set; } = default!;
        public bool Company { get; set; }
        public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string? Abn { get; set; }
        public bool IsWarrantyCompany { set; get; }
        public bool RequiresPartsPayment { set; get; }
        public string? ClientFirstName { get; set; }
        public string ClientLastName { get; set; } = default!;
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        public string? MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public string? Phone { get; set; }
        public string? Address1 { get; set; }
        public string? Address2 { get; set; }
        public string? BankName { get; set; }
        public string? BankBSB { get; set; }
        public string? BankAccount { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateDeActivated { get; set; }
        public bool Activity { get; set; }

        // One warranty company client to a job.
        public int? WarrantyCompanyId { get; set; }

        public virtual Job? WarrantyCompany { get; set; }

        // One suburb to a client.
        public int? SuburbId { get; set; }
        public virtual Suburb? Suburb { get; set; }

        // If its a warranty company then we simply link it one to one to the brand id.
        public virtual Brand? Brand { get; set; }

        // Multiple notes for each client.
        public virtual ICollection<Note>? ClientNotes { get; set; }

        // Multiple jobs for each client.
        public virtual ICollection<Job>? Jobs { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Job> WarrantyCompanyJobs { get; } = default!;
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
#nullable disable
}
```

This is my Note entity:

```
using JobsLedger.INTERFACES;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace JobsLedger.DATA.ENTITIES
{
    public class Note : IEntityBase, IAuditedEntityBase
    {
#nullable enable
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Details { get; set; }

        public int? JobId { get; set; }
        public virtual Job? Job { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        public virtual Client? Client { get; set; }

        public int? NoteTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual NoteType? NoteType { get; set; }
    }
#nullable disable
}
```

Using Fluent API and so this is the way I am adding the notes to the client.. bear in mind that I can have multiple notes for each client...

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
            .HasOne(j => j.Client)
            .WithMany(s => s.ClientNotes)
            .HasForeignKey(j => j.ClientId)
            .IsRequired(false);
```

The notes are however optional.. you can one or many notes etc.. I have a number of relationships that are similar to this and I believe they work but for some reason its indicating I have another property with the same name..

It might be a client note - need it to link to the client, or it might be a job note - link it to a job. Cant have a clientId for a job note or vice vesa.. eg the client Id should be null if its a job note..

What am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: Why do you have nullable ICollections and virtuals, they are nullable by default

Comment: Didnt know that... Does it matter with this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, other than the nullable ICollections and virtuals i can't see anything obvious.

Comment: Me neither.. :(

Comment: Have you tried removing the nullable and running again? Otherwise IDK - but ill watch to see what someone else thinks.

Comment: It is the EF core version.. I did take the nullables off and it still failed with the same error message..

Comment: Most likely you have fluent call like `modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(e => e.ClientNotes)` before the shown relationship configuration.

Comment: Ivan Stoev... You know I did check that, but you know what.. I had another look and buried in the midst of the list was this... modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(c => c.ClientNotes).HasMaxLength(1000);

Answer (score 0):

Previously I had similar issue as mentioned.

> The property or navigation 'Brand' cannot be added to the entity type 'VehicleDetail' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'VehicleDetail'.

I had relationship between VehicleDetail and Choice entities as below

```
public class Choice:RecordHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IList<VehicleDetail> VehicleDetail { get; set; }
}
public class VehicleDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Choice Type { get; set; }
    public Choice Brand { get; set; }
}
```

So to resolve this issue, I updated Choice entity model as below

```
 public class Choice:RecordHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IList<VehicleDetail> VehicleDetailType { get; set; }
    public IList<VehicleDetail> VehicleDetailBrand { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent Api configuration as below

```
public class VehicleDetailConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<VehicleDetail>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<VehicleDetail> builder)
    {

        builder.HasOne<Choice>(a => a.Brand).
            WithMany(b => b.VehicleDetailBrand).
            HasForeignKey(c => c.BrandId).
            HasConstraintName("Fk_VehicleDetail_Brand_Choice").
           IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne<Choice>(a => a.Type).
            WithMany(b => b.VehicleDetailType).
            HasForeignKey(c => c.TypeId).        
         HasConstraintName("FK_VehicleDetail_Type_Choice").IsRequired().
         OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

May be helpful with similar issue.